# Finding a volume of a solid by using integration. Calc III level.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the volume of the solid with the plane $z = 0$ as the bottom, the cylinder $x^2+y^2=4$ as the side, and the plane $z = 3−x−y$ as the top.

So I set 
$$0 < z < 3-x-y,\; 0 < x < 2, \;0 < y < 2$$

Is that a correct way to set up an integration?
or do i have to use different coordinate system?

it's simple but i just want to clarify!

Comment: Your $z$ direction is correct but how have you taken into account your cylindrical boundary?

Answer (score 2):

That is not correct--the region you have denoted is a $2\times2$ unit square, not a cylinder.  For the correct volume, compute:
$$\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{-\sqrt{4-y^2}}^{\sqrt{4-y^2}}\int_{0}^{3-x-y}\;dz\;dx\;dy$$

This may be simplified by going to a cylindrical coordinate system, by using the substitutions $x=r\cos\theta,\;y=r\sin\theta$:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{3-r(\cos\theta - \sin\theta)}r\;dz\;dr\;d\theta$$